# Future<T>.get() stuck when the runnable throws exception--while running on separate executor service?

Tags: java, future, executorservice, freeze, executor

A repro here:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Hello!");

        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        Future<Integer> f = exec.submit(() -> x());

        f.get();

        System.out.println("f.get() returned");

        exec.shutdownNow();

        System.out.println("Good bye!");
    }

    private static Integer x() {
        throw new RuntimeException("An unfortunate event");
    }
}
```

The output only shows "Hello!" and the exception stacktrace, then gets the program hangs forever.

The changes below kind of work around the problem, but any idea why the execution hangs in the code above?

Using the common thread pool does NOT hang:

```
Future<Integer> f = ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(() -> x());
```

Wrapping the call around try/catch lets the application exit normally:

```
Future<Integer> f = exec.submit(() -> x());

try {
    f.get();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Exception thrown from main in `get()` as expected. This means that execution **does not continue** past that line. Executor service never shut down so you have a running non-daemon thread. The JVM does not exit. Can you explain what behaviour you expected?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Now that you pointed it out, that's... obvious. I need more sleep/coffee :-)

For console applications like this, is there a pragmatic way to safely kill the thread pool so the application can exit besides catching the exception? Maybe try/finally and make sure the thread pool shutdown?

Comment: If you want the JVM to exit even if tasks are still running then just use daemon threads. Otherwise you'll need to faff around with shutdown hooks and the like.

Comment: Alternatively, use a framework like Spring Boot which handles a lot of this stuff for you. But it's a big framework so you need a fairly complex application before it becomes worth it to bring something like that in.

Comment: The CommonPool uses daemon threads by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always hard to find a good example of `try-finally` and its appropriate usage. I think it's the case.

```
try {
    f.get();
    System.out.println("f.get() returned");
} finally {
    exec.shutdownNow();
}
```

The exception thrown from `f.get();` wasn't handled, the main thread failed. But the application still contains non-daemon threads manageable by the `ExecutorService` to which you have no direct access.

Comment: Easier in this case - call `shutdown` _after_ submitting the task _before_ calling `get()`.

Comment: Thanks! This works. I'm choosing to using daemon threads in my thread pool, since I don't really care for them to exit cleanly.